# How can I reclaim a company email account from former Canadian distributor?

Tags: email, google

A former company rep in Canada took our (COMPANY DBA)@GMAIL.COM address for use in representing our products in Canada. She has moved on and seems to have discarded the name as all that seem so come through to us is phishing and SPAM with that address now.

Some time ago, I asked kindly for her to surrender it but got no response. Is there a way that I can get this address back since it is clearly our trademark that has been in use in Canada for 32 years?

Comment: This may be more suitable for the [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) portal.

Comment: Abandon it. I never trust company emails from "@<insert generic mail service>.com" accounts. Register a corresponding domain (if you have company.com then register company.ca, etc) and host your own email there (make sure both domains go to your site). Gives the email account more credibility and you control of the account.

Comment: just open an new email account `The.Real.companyName@gmail.com`